# Even if "although" is omitted, can this sentence still have the same meaning?

Tags: grammar

For example,

1. Although I know he is honest, I don't like him
2. Knowing he is honest, I don't like him

I think 2 has the same meaning as 1 even if "although" is omitted because it's most natural to read 2 as 1.
What do you think?

Comment: You've done more than just omit *although*; you've also omitted *I* and changed *know* to *knowing*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually interpret these as opposite of each other in a way.

1 -> *I don't like him **even though** he is honest*

2 -> *I don't like him **because** he is honest*

That said, "Knowing he is honest, I **still** don't like him" *would* be equivalent to 1.

Comment: What about these sentences? **(1) Everyone knowing who would have stolen the money, no one dared to say he was the robber**  and
 **(2) Although everyone knew who would have stolen the money, no one dared to say he was the robber.** Do these sentences have the same meaning ?

Comment: The difference between these sentences is definitely more subtle than the originals, but it is there. By applying a similar transformation we can see it more clearly: (1) *No one dared say who stole the money **because** they knew who it was*. (2) *No one dared say who stole the money **even though** they knew who it was*. In 1 there is a direct correlation between who the robber was and why nobody is saying anything (perhaps they are scared of him?). In 2 they have other reasons for not saying anything (like not wanting to rat out their friend).